# Wordpress search through meta_value thats an array

Tags: php, wordpress

If i use an array for a meta value can i see if a value is in the array when querying it? I have a website that has events that has dates attached to it as a meta value and i need to see if an event is on a certain date through a search.

```
$dates[] = 05/02/2016
$dates[] = 06/02/2016
$dates[] = 06/02/2016
update_post_meta($event, 'show_dates', $dates);
```

if i add this to an event how could i check if the 'show_dates' contains a date searched for? below is what i have tried already

```
 $wp_query->set('post_status', array('publish', 'future'));
 $wp_query->set("meta_key", "show_dates");
 $wp_query->set("orderby", "meta_value");
 $wp_query->set("order", "ASC");

        $startDate = parseDatePicker($_GET['StartDate'], new \DateTime());

        if (!is_null($startDate)) {

            $wp_query->set("meta_query", array(
                array(
                    'key' => "show_dates",
                    'value' => $startDate->format("d/m/Y"),
                    'compare' => 'IN'
                )
            ));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so it turns out the answer to this was easier than i expected. As Wordpress serializes the data in the array you can use `LIKE` instead of `IN` which will check the serialized array to see if it contains that date.

```
 $wp_query->set('post_status', array('publish', 'future'));
 $wp_query->set("meta_key", "show_dates");
 $wp_query->set("orderby", "meta_value");
 $wp_query->set("order", "ASC");

    $startDate = parseDatePicker($_GET['StartDate'], new \DateTime());

    if (!is_null($startDate)) {

        $wp_query->set("meta_query", array(
            array(
                'key' => "show_dates",
                'value' => $startDate->format("d/m/Y"),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ));
    }
```

my next problem was how to work with a range I managed to figure this out and have posted below incase nayone else has a similar problem

```
if (!is_null($startDate) && !is_null($endDate) && ($startDate->format('d/m/Y') != $endDate->format('d/m/Y'))) {

            $wp_query->set("relation", "OR");

            $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
            $period = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval, $endDate);
            $dates[] = $startDate->format('d/m/Y');

            foreach($period as $day){

                $dates[] = array(
                    'key' => "next_showing_date",
                    'value' => $day->format('d/m/Y'),
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                );

            }

            $wp_query->set("meta_query", $dates);

        }
```